# Connecting an external monitor to an early 2008 iMac, due to a problem with the built-in display

Tags: imac

I want to connect my early 2008 iMac to an external monitor. Is it possible?

The problem is my early 2008 iMac is good in condition but the display is cloudy and has blue patches on the screen. I am not able to work. I want to use an external display but the issue is that I cant find a suitable adapter.

Please provide a solution as I want to connect to an external monitor. Is it possible via USB?

Or is there a mini DVI to HDMI adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [mini DVI port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI) on the rear of the [2008 20" iMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.4-20-inch-aluminum-early-2008-penryn-specs.html), shown here on the right hand side:

[image: Ports on rear of 2008 iMac 20"]

The connector

[image: Mini DVI connector]

A mini DVI to DVI adapter:

[image: Mini DVI to DVI adapter]

Alternatively, you could indeed get a mini DVI to HDMI cable:

[image: Mini DVI to HDMI cable]

USB to HDMI *adapters* certainly do exist... However, the 2008 iMac only has USB 2.0 and, as such, a USB 2.0 to HDMI adapter might have poor performance, and almost certainly not be able to display HD content. Also, be aware that many of the USB 2.0 to HDMI ***cables*** (rather than *adapters*), that are on the market, are actually just for *charging* capabilities.

You could also just replace your built-in display using one of the many guides available, such as this one on ifixit: [iMac Intel 20" EMC 2133 and 2210 Display Panel Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+20-Inch+EMC+2133+and+2210+Display+Panel+Replacement/998).