2008 iMac screen problem
I have a 2008 iMac, running El Cap, screen unusable, went stripey and unreadable in full screen mode, using Firefox. Can anyone please tell me:
Likely issue, graphics card? Repairable? No response from firm approached.
Given it might be the same cost, I'd like to replace it anyway with a 2010(?) iMac (running nothing newer than High Sierra 10.13.4, I have 32bit apps), but how would I migrate, without a usable interface? My back up is out of date, how would I get important files off? Software licences?
Last question, excuse my ignorance but if I booted with the right cable from the mini DVI port to a 2nd iMac, would I get a mirrored screen on the 2nd?
Really grateful for any help here, I depend on this old iMac for work.

Can you try an external monitor? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444707/connecting-an-external-monitor-to-an-early-2008-imac-due-to-a-problem-with-the

Thanks. I'm told it wouldn't work with another iMac, and needs a DVI monitor. I'll stick to the new Mac, funds are short.

I'd say definitely a capacitor on the graphics card.  I had that exact issue and was able to identify the bad capacitor(s) simply by looking at them.  Bad ones will be bulged out at the top.  Soldered on a couple new ones and it's still working fine now 3 years later.   However, that's some OLD hardware.

It's certainly a hardware fault somewhere that's affecting either the screen itself or the graphics circuitry. (Those old iMacs had a tendency to blow capacitors.)
No one can answer whether it's repairable without seeing it; and the cost of repair will be up to the repairer.
If the graphics circuitry is faulty, then you won't get any video out to any kind of external screen.
If I remember correctly, you could try using Target Disk Mode to connect the old iMac as a disk on the newer one; and Migration Assistant should be able to read it directly. (You'd need to use FireWire.)
The last OS to support 32-bit apps is Mojave, which may give you a better choice of hardware; though I'd really suggest that you purchase newer, up-to-date versions of your software or alternative apps. Relying on 16-year-old hardware and software for your work leaves you at the mercy of fate, as you've found out.
There's no guarantee that a secondhand 2010 Mac won't have a hardware failure sometime soon either.
If you were using Time Machine previously, you should be able to trigger a new backup just by plugging in the external drive, without needing to use the interface. Everyone should always have an up-to-date backup, but that's doubly true for very old hardware that you depend on.

Thank you benwiggy
